# Regex not working for finding within range in word document

Tags: regex, powershell

Regex not working, content between two sections to be extracted (functions works fine, but may be im not mentioning right regex for lookup for this)

```
ExtractFromWordDoc"D:\Scan.doc" '(?:\d{2}\.\d).*(?:Non-Payment)'  '(?:\d{2}\.\d).*(?:Financial covenants and other obligation)'
```

Word Document Content (information between 29.1 and 29.2 needs to be extracted)

29.1    Non-payment

An Obligor does not pay on the due date any amount payable pursuant to a Finance Document at the place at and in the currency in which it is expressed to be payable unless:

(a) its failure to pay is caused by:
(i) administrative or technical error; or
(b) [payment is made within:
(i) (in the case of paragraph (a)(i) above), [         ] Business Days of its due date;

29.2    Financial covenants and other obligations

(a) Any requirement of Clause 27 (Financial covenants) is not satisfied [or an Obligor does not comply with the provisions of Clause 26 (Information Undertakings)] [and/or Clause 28 (General Undertakings)] .

```
function ExtractFromWordDoc{
Param([string]$SourceFile, [string]$SearchKeyword1, [string]$SearchKeyword2)

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($SourceFile,$false,$true)
$sel = $word.Selection 
$paras = $doc.Paragraphs 
foreach ($para in $paras) 
{ 
    if ($para.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword1)
    {
        $startPosition = $para.Range.Start
       }
    if ($para.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword2)
    {
        $endPosition = $para.Range.Start
        break
    }
} 

[array]$content=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$doc.Range($startPosition, $endPosition).Copy()
$content=Get-Clipboard -Raw
$content = $content -replace "'", ""

# cleanup com objects
$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($doc) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just one minor error in the Regex.

The sample text is `Non-payment` but the regex matches `Non-Payment` (Case-Sensitive)

If you change `'(?:\d{2}\.\d).*(?:Non-Payment)'` to `'(?:\d{2}\.\d).*(?:Non-payment)'` it should work.

Another note is that you are missing the `s` from `obligations` in `(?:\d{2}\.\d).*(?:Financial covenants and other obligation)` but I don't foresee that it will cause a problem.

**Disclaimer**: I didn't test your code, only your regex.

**Edit:**

I tested the following

```
function ExtractFromWordDoc{
Param([string]$SourceFile, [string]$SearchKeyword1, [string]$SearchKeyword2)

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($SourceFile,$false,$true)
$sel = $word.Selection 
$paras = $doc.Paragraphs 
foreach ($para in $paras) 
{ 
    if ($para.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword1)
    {
        #"Point 1"
        $startPosition = $para.Range.Start
       }
    if ($para.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword2)
    {
        #"Point 2"
        $endPosition = $para.Range.Start
        break
    }
} 

[array]$content=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$doc.Range($startPosition, $endPosition).Copy()
$content=Get-Clipboard -Raw
$content = $content -replace "'", ""

# cleanup com objects
$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($doc) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}

ExtractFromWordDoc "C:\testing\test.doc" '(?:\d{2}\.\d).*(?:Non-payment)'  '(?:\d{2}\.\d).*(?:Financial covenants and other obligation)'
```

And the output was in the clipboard was:

```
29.1 Non-payment
An Obligor does not pay on the due date any amount payable pursuant to a Finance Document at the place at and in the currency in which it is expressed to be payable unless:
(a) its failure to pay is caused by: (i) administrative or technical error; or (b) [payment is made within: (i) (in the case of paragraph (a)(i) above), [ ] Business Days of its due date;
```

If I add `$content` to the end of the function, it outputs this text to the console.

Comment: tried, didnt work... gets the first section line right... but for second keyword it doesn't

Comment: I tested it and it works fine, it matches the text between the regex up to but not including `29.2 Financial covenants and other obligations` and below - Is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: because i search in document of 370 pages, its giving different result back as word search may exist at other place..  but number at front of it can't be... so don't know why it isnt working... any suggestions

Comment: do we need to clear clipboard... as that what is used to copy

Comment: Are you able to provide examples of the strings that are causing false matches, I.E the first line of the match, and then the line that appears immediately after the match?

Answer (score 0):

To store the found text, I suggest using the [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

```
function ExtractFromWordDoc{
  Param([string]$SourceFile, [string]$SearchKeyword1, [string]$SearchKeyword2)

  $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
  $word.Visible = $false
  $doc = $word.Documents.Open($SourceFile, $false, $true)

  $sb = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

  $text = $null

  foreach ($para in $doc.Paragraphs)
  {
    if ($para.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword1)
    {
      while (1)
      {
        [void]$sb.AppendLine($foreach.current.Range.Text)
        if (-not $foreach.MoveNext())
        {
          break # we ran out of paragraphs
        }
        if ($foreach.current.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword2)
        {
          $text = $sb.ToString() # the searched text was found
          break
        }
      }
      break
    }
  }

  $text # let's return something usefull

  # cleanup com objects
  $doc.Close()
  $save=$false
  $word.Quit([ref]$save)
  [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($doc) | Out-Null
  [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null
  [System.GC]::Collect()
  [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}

ExtractFromWordDoc 'C:\testing\test.doc' '^\s*\d\d\.\d\s+Non-payment' '^\s*\d\d\.\d\s+Financial covenants and other obligation'
```